# Как определить столкновение шаров?

Tags: python, python-3.x, canvas, tkinter

Как можно определить столкновение двух шаров в Canvas? То есть эти два шара двигаются, но когда их оболчки сталкиваются, надо чтобы они шли в обратных направлениях. Как сделать это движение обратно я знаю, но не получается зафиксировать их столкновкние.

Comment: Необходимо обработать координаты. Если они где-то совпадают, то пишите необходимый функционал для обратного направления

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вспоминаем курс математики=)

Центры шаров не могут быть ближе, чем r1 + r2. Если они ближе - значит шары пересекаются.

По теореме Пифагора находим расстояние между центрами.

```
l = sqrt( (x1 - x2)^2 + (y1 - y2)^2 )
```

И потом если `l <= r1 + r2` - делаем то что нужно.

Comment: лучше проверять квадрат расстояния - не придется брать корень

Comment: @StrangerintheQ А можно брать корень - не придется проверять квадрат расстояния=) Согласен, можно и по вашему, будет даже ефективнее, возможно)

Comment: я полагаю, это проверка коллизии, даже предварительная, обычно в этом месте я делаю именно так, так как операция это частая.